# Transposing lines where no. of lines and length is dependent on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, design-patterns

I am trying to generate two sets of string images. 
1st.

```
% % % 
% % % % % 
% % 
%
```

2nd.

```
  %
% %
% % %
% % % %
```

Note that the 2nd image is the same as the 1st image, just rotated counter-clockwise.

The number of lines and length of each line in the 1st image is based on a list, which can be of any length and consist of strictly positive numbers. In this example, our list is:

```
list = [3, 5, 2, 1]
```

I am having some trouble getting the 2nd image. For the first image, I have made use of the following function:

```
for e in list:
  print(int(e) * '% '
```

Which seems to work. I am just not sure how to go about the 2nd image. I have some ideas around producing each row where I can find the highest element in list, find its index (in this example list[1]), and then incorporate "  " on either side, depending on its distance to the beginning of the list and the end and going from there, but I am just not sure.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Find largest number (here 5). First line in second image represents this height 5, second line is height 4 and so on. For each column show only a percent where the column height is same or larger than height of current line.

Comment: Pedantic: You aren't showing a transpose here. The second row in the first output has five `%`s, the second column in the second output only has four `%`s. Should there be a fifth in the second output to match the counts in your `list`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Generating 1st image.

```
a=[['%' for i in range(j)] for j in [3,5,2,1]]
for i in a:
    print(*i)
% % %
% % % % %
% %
%
```

---

You can generate 2nd image from 1st image.

```
from itertools import zip_longest #use izip_longest for python2
b=list(zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=' '))[::-1]
for i in b:
    print(*i)

  %
  %
% %
% % %
% % % %
```